# How do I continue downloading files with ftp command after session is closed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I need to create a script in Linux to get from server multiple files. After downloading files started need to close the session but without stopping the download.

How do I do this?

Comment: You can not download files without a session.  You could do as aix suggests below but that just transfers the session to a different non-interface session it still needs an ftp connection (session).

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is to continue downloading files in the background after you exit your login session what you need is [nohup](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?nohup%201).

For example:

```
$ nohup download-script &
$ exit
```

counting on that you created download-script containing your commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `screen` command to create a "screen" session on your machine. Screen is a full-screen window manager that multiplexes a physical terminal between several processes (typically interactive shells).
Screens can be detached while leaving the background processes running, and then later re-attached if you wish. This allows you to close a terminal window or close a session without losing your processes. This is especially useful if you need to leave something running for a long period of time or have a temperamental connection to your server.

Run `man screen` to see how to use it. (hint: It's painfully simple)

Alternatively, if you simply need to run a process or script in the background, but don't want to keep a "session" open, consider using:

```
progname [arguments] &
```

Any command terminated with `&` will execute in the background. Of course this implies that your program doesn't require user intervention.

Comment: You could also install and try `tmux`, another terminal multiplexer. It's very similar, but I prefer tmux to screen.